# Google Map - display specific markers popup using a list of markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code:

```
<?php //include_once("connectionmarker.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Cherrybird</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
         <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   (function() {

    window.onload = function() {

        // Creating a new map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8967,-1.40225),
          zoom: 18,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

    var customIcons = {
      Now: {
        icon: 'img/fourmarker.png',

      },
      Soon: {
        icon: 'img/marker.png',

      }
    };




        // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var list = document.getElementById('list');

        $.getJSON("connectionmarker.php", function(data) { 

         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){

            // Looping through the JSON data

                var datanew = data[i] 
                //alert (data[i].Availibility);
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(datanew.Lat, datanew.Lon);

                    var iconimage = datanew.Availibility;
                    var icon = customIcons[iconimage] || {};

                // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    title: datanew.Propertynanu
                });
                // add items
                var listItem= document.createElement('li')
                listItem.className = "content";
                listItem.innerHTML = "House:" + datanew.Propertynanu + "<br />" + datanew.Postcode + "<br />" + datanew.Availibility + "<br />" ;
                list.appendChild(listItem);


                // Creating a closure to retain the correct data
                (function(marker, datanew) {

                    // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {

                    //"Id:" + data[i].Id + "<br /> Property Name/Number:" + data[i].Propertynanu + "<br /> Rooms:" + data[i].Rooms
                        infoWindow.setContent("House:" + datanew.Propertynanu + "<br />" + datanew.Postcode + "<br />" + datanew.Availibility + "<br />" );
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });


                })(marker, datanew);




            }
        });
    }

})();


  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

What I want to do is dynamically add the list item to the page in divs then allow the user to click each div the relevent infoWindow will display on the map. I have done this with openlayers but now need to do it with Google maps.

I have got as far as adding the the list to page with the following:

```
// add items
                var listItem= document.createElement('div')
                listItem.className = "content";
                listItem.innerHTML = "House:" + datanew.Propertynanu + "<br />" + datanew.Postcode + "<br />" + datanew.Availibility + "<br />" ;
                list.appendChild(listItem);
```

The next step is to get it to display the infoWindow for the relevent marker when it is clicked in the list. Can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that makes a clickable sidebar (translated from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html

The key is keeping an array of markers so that you can access them to open the infowindow.

Answer (score 0):

Register an event listener that will display the info window. It's basically the same code that runs from a marker.